# Setting Charset for static files in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis, content-type

How can I ensure IIS (and Cassini) send css and js files with the content-type header (ie text/css;charset=UTF-8)?

Answer (score 5):

Having just come up with the same question I found the answer [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1155439.aspx) (for IIS7/7.5, but expect this should also work for Casini):

Either:

- Directly add the `; charset=utf-8` to the mime type in the mine types configuration in IIS manager.
- Edit the web.config:

```
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".rss" mimeType="text/xml; charset=utf-8"/>
      </staticContent>
    [...]
```

Comment: You would probably need to also add `<remove fileExtension=".html" />` before the `mimeMap` definition, to remove the default definition. You'll get a "duplicate key" error otherwise.

Comment: We've had some issues with IE 10 using this approach where the server returns a `406 Not Acceptable` error when used with `text/css; charset=utf-8`.